# Oracle if/else in results

Tags: oracle

Just wondering if there's a way of doing something like the below in Oracle, where if a returned result is one value you output one thing, else you output something else?

For example:

```
select if(COL1,1:'TRUE',0:'FALSE') from TABLE1;
```

Thanks in advance C

Answer (score 3):

```
SQL> create table t1 (c1 number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into t1 values(1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t1 values(0);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select decode(c1, 1, 'TRUE', 0, 'FALSE') from t1;

DECOD
-----
TRUE
FALSE
```

Answer (score 3):

A CASE expression can also be used:
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/expressions004.htm#SQLRF20037

```
select case 
    when col1 =  1 
        then 'TRUE'
    when col1 = 0
        then 'FALSE'
    else
        'SOMETHING ELSE'
    end
from table1;
```

This is also a good discussion regarding DECODE and CASE:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193692/case-vs-decode